# SWRevealViewController and other view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller

In my app, I use a `SWRevealViewController` for the side menu, and I have it set up correctly. My problem is that from a view controller that has a side menu, I have a segue to go to another view controllers that doesn't use SWRevealViewController. Then on action go back to the SWRevealViewController. (a quiz controller). For some reason the menu button stops displaying the menu. Here is what is happening:

[image: Gif]

(sorry for the bad quality, used quicktime to record, then online converter to gif).

And here is my storyboard layout:
[image: pic]

The segue to quiz controller is push.

How can I get the button to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer a while ago. All you have to do is create an unwind segue to your original controller. If you do not know how to do this, follow along.

- **Add the unwind method to your original controller**

My controller is called`QuizViewController`, yours is probably different.

```
// In QuizViewController.m
...
- (void)unwindToQuiz:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // Get data from sender by segue.sourceViewController
}
```

This method will be called when the segue happens, put code in here similar to a `prepareForSegue` method.

- **Next create the segue in storyboard**

In the controller you push right click drag (control-click) from view controller to exit and select your `-unwindToQuiz` method.

Now select your segue from the sidebar, then add an identifier to the segue.

**TIP: if you dont want to initiate the segue programmatically, drag from a UI element (like UIButton) and drag to exit. No need for identifier).

To initiate segue do `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentfier" sender:self];

***And you're done! It doesn't work with push because `revealViewController` property becomes nil***